# Why the Python Program is exceeding time limit while the C++ program with same logic isn't?

Tags: python, c++

I created my Python Program for the question:

> Check if the door is open or closed [Check if the door is open or closed](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/check-if-the-door-is-open-or-closed/0)

> Given n doors and n persons. The doors are numbered from 1 to n and persons are given id’s numbered from 1 to n. Each door can have only two statuses ie open (1) or closed (0) . Initially all the doors have status closed. Find the final status of all the doors, when all the persons have changed the status of the doors of which they are authorized. i.e. if status open then change the status to closed and vice versa. A person with id ‘i’ is authorized to change the status of door numbered ‘j’ if ‘j’ is a multiple of ‘i’.

> Note: A person has to change the current status of all the doors for which he is authorized exactly once.

> Example:
> Input : 3
> Output : 1 0 0

> Explanation : Initially status of rooms 0 0 0 person with id 2 changes room 2 to open ie (0 1 0) person with id 1 changes room 1, 2, 3 status (1 0 1) person with id 3 changes room 3 status ie (1 0 0)

> Input:
> The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the no of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case contains an integer n.

> Output:
> For each test case in a new line print the n space separated integers  either (1 or 0) depending on the status of the ith door where 1 denotes the door is open and a 0 denotes door is closed.

> Constraints:
> 1 <= T <= 100
> 1 <= N <= 1000

> Example:
> Input:
> 2
> 3
> 5
> Output:
> 1 0 0
> 1 0 0 1 0

For this I wrote the Python Code:

```
def doorcheck(n):

    doors = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
    for x in range(n):
        if (x+1) % (i+1) == 0:
            if(doors[x] == 0):
                doors[x] = 1
            else:
                doors[x] = 0
    
    print(' '.join(map(str, doors)))

t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    doorcheck(n)
```

which is working fine but exceeds the time limit of  3.346sec.
While the below C++ code executes in 0.11 sec

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int a[n+1]={0};
        for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<n+1;j++)
            {
                if(j%i == 0)
                {   
                    if(a[j] == 0)
                        a[j]=1;
                    else if(a[j] == 1)
                        a[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++)
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me understand the logic behind the Python Program being more time taking.

Comment: You're trying to compare execution time of compiled binary and interpreted script. Ofc, C++ will be much faster, especially in such a simple tasks.

Comment: The for loops in Python are slower, why the nested for-loop over all doors/persons costs some time. You'd better just loop over the multiples of (i+1) in the inner loop. Also, you can spare an if-statement if you just change the value by `doors[i] = 1-doors[i]`

Comment: Although you didn't ask for it, here is an improved version of your code (I added a timer func to it for testing) [main.py](https://repl.it/repls/IdolizedSurefootedHack#main.py)

Answer (score 1):

Python scripts aren't compiled to machine code but rather passed to the python interpreter to parse the text in the script, convert it to some representation (like AST tree) and start to execute them step by step . It's like a command line tool that you pass the arguments to then they get parsed, processed and the tool then acts as required . This requires a very long time compared to the time taken by the cpu to execute compiled machine code.

On the other hand, when C++ source code is compiled the compiler parses the text, generate an AST tree and finally generate the machine code which is going to be put in an executable file like (exe, elf and dll) and when executed they will be loaded into memory and the cpu will start executing them directly . So you notice that compiling C++ sources is a consuming time process but the good thing is that you pay it once while in Python you pay it each time you run the script